# Make a condition about date interval in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I just want to add a notification in my system, but I'm having a hard time.

As you seen below my `Products` table has an `ExpDate` column and I want to notify if that `Products` is about to expire.

First I get the date 30 days before the expiration and get the date today.

What I wanted to do is just use some condition like `datenow => alarmdate` or if `datenow` = or less than `alarmdate`.

Is this possible? Or do I just have to use the `SqlDataReader` instead?

```
SELECT
    ProductDesc,
    ProductQty,
    ExpDate,
    CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) AS datenow,
    DATEADD(DAY, -30, ExpDate) AS alarmdate
FROM
    Products
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at here. A database engine doesn't continually check the data you have in your database to check if X or Y conditions are met. Once it's in your database, it's in the database; it doesn't check the validity again until *something* changes (and I don't mean the time). That might be, for example, an `UPDATE` to the row, or a `CONSTRAINT` is added. If you want to find out about "expiring" data, you need to implement a scheduled task to interrogate your data then notify you in an appropriate way. How you do that is a *completely* different question.

Comment: You might want to have a look at SSIS - there you can define a dataflow, mail notifications and so on in a package which then can be sheduled via SQL Server Agent Jobs... this should help you in the task at hand.

Comment: `SqlDependency` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get a list of product from `product` table for which you need to send the notification.

```
SELECT
  ProductDesc,
  ProductQty,
  ExpDate
FROM Products
WHERE GETDATE() > = DATEADD( DAY, - 30, ExpDate )
```

you can use this query to creating a `SQL Job` and schedule it to run everyday to send an email notification.

1. [Creating SQL Server Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-transact-sql-job-step?view=sql-server-ver15),
   2. [Configure Email Notification](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5533/anatomy-of-a-sql-agent-email-notification/)